# Preserving stokeEnd change from animation without isRemovedOnCompletion set to false

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I have a progress circle that animates. I can hit a button and it animates to 20%, if I hit the button again it animates to 40%. I am setting `isRemovedOnCompletion` to `false`. However each time I perform an animation a new animation is added to the `CAShapelayer`. I imagine this is not good for performance. Is there a better way to do this?

Dummy code:

```
@IBAction func didTapAnimate(_ sender: Any) {
        let animateStroke = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animateStroke.fromValue = index > 0 ? progressPts[index - 1] : 0
        animateStroke.toValue = progressPts[index]
        animateStroke.duration = 2.0
        animateStroke.fillMode = .forwards
        animateStroke.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        circleLayer.add(animateStroke, forKey: "MyAnimation")
        index+=1
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no need to remove previous animation as per my knowledge only one animation layer is used for single key so animation automatically replace with previous one.

> A string that identifies the animation. Only one animation per unique
>   key is added to the layer. The special key kCATransition is
>   automatically used for transition animations. You may specify nil for
>   this parameter.

So only the last animation occupies the memory previous animation automatically deallocated.

Comment: you can also cross check it with memory graph

Comment: @AbuUlHassan sorry, I did not understood what you try to say can you please explain in brief.

Comment: sorry auto correct spell changed my meaning, 
I was saving we all know behavior of keys every single uniques key preserves only one value to it adding other value just replaces the old value, and our mind not clicked this thing, Thanks to you who led us to this point.

Comment: just kidding, still spell mistake saving instead of saying :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove previous animation from circleLayer by calling `removeAnimation(forKey:"yourkey")`

```
@IBAction func didTapAnimate(_ sender: Any) {
        circleLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "MyAnimation")
        let animateStroke = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animateStroke.fromValue = index > 0 ? progressPts[index - 1] : 0
        animateStroke.toValue = progressPts[index]
        animateStroke.duration = 2.0
        animateStroke.fillMode = .forwards
        animateStroke.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        circleLayer.add(animateStroke, forKey: "MyAnimation")
        index+=1
    }
```

Comment: it will also remove other animation. better to use circleLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: <#T##String#>)

Comment: yes Thanks it will be more appropriate i should update the answer ;)